# Comprehensive graphing and charting solutions...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, graph, scatter-plot

I have need to produce LINE, BAR, and PIE charts in Rails.  I have found several that do all these.  However the one caveat is that I can never find a solution that does all as well as XY-SCATTER.  I've looked at Gruff,Scruffy,Gnuplot, etc. and none of them do "everything".  Can anyone recommend a local (i.e. doesn't require network connectivity) library that can accommodate?  GoogleCharts isn't an option as some of this will occur on closed networks.

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Open Flash Chart Plugin for Ruby on Rails - Graphs](http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart)

Comment: aaaarrrrrggggggggggh!!! domain/scoping issues with OFC.  I already have a class named Chart and it wants to take it over.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind commercial solutions, take a look at [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/cdruby.html).

Comment: I'm not necessarily opposed to commercial solutions, but it does need to give me something the others can't/don't..."support" aside.

Answer (score 0):

[FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) is pretty good if you don't have a problem with Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)? I'm not a web developer myself but it seems that, although not implemented in Rails, you can call the chart API and display the generated image.

Looking at the available [chart types](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html), it can give you all the types you want.

**Edit**: A search turned up this [google-chart-on-rails wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/google-charts-on-rails/).

Comment: Yes, but unless you acquire the "premium" version, you must have network access to use it.

Comment: Network access to google? Yes, I suppose. But I thought that wouldnt be a problem, wont your web application be connected?

Comment: No.  This will be running on an intranet.